# invariants of a Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, lie-algebras

What does it mean by "constructing invariants" in algebraic topology or algebra in general?

How to define a "invariant" in algebra?

What does it mean by the "invariant of a Lie algebra"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting Wikipedia:

> [In mathematics, an invariant is a property of a class of mathematical objects that remains unchanged when transformations of a certain type are applied to the objects.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_%28mathematics%29)

Typically, for a Lie algebra we are interested under properties unchanged under isomorphisms. Examples include the dimension, the center, the universal enveloping algebra... For differential graded Lie algebras (of which "usual" Lie algebras are special cases), we're also interested in notions invariant under quasi-isomorphism. So for example [Lie algebra cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology).

Comment: how about a differential invariant? Does it mean invariant under diffeomorphism?

Comment: In what context? For a manifold? Yes, it means invariant under diffeomorphism.